# video not upload from android to server

Tags: android, video

I want to upload the video from android to php server.The video is uploading only one mobile.If i upload the video from another mobile means video not upload.How to upload video from all mobile
This is my coding.

```
 class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String sResponse = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd.setMessage("loading");
        pd.show();
    }



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            String url =Serviceurl.url + "video";

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);


            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            int i=0;

            File sourceFile = new File(selectedPath);

            entity.addPart("video", new FileBody(sourceFile));
            entity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody("66"));


            httpPost.setEntity(entity);


            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            entity.writeTo(bytes);

            String content = bytes.toString();
            String content1 = entity.toString();
            Log.e("MultiPartEntityRequest:",content);
            Log.e("MultiPartEntity---11:",content1);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                    localContext);
            sResponse = EntityUtils.getContentCharSet(response.getEntity());

            System.out.println("sResponse : " + sResponse);




        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);

        }
        return sResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
        try {


            pd.dismiss();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So you have exception. Please tell them. And tell exactly what happens an what not happens and what happens instead. Why dont youtell whichresponse you get?